# How to apply a function over rows in a list of arrays

Tags: r, list, multidimensional-array

I have not been able to get a solution to my problem yet despite discussing it with several people so hopefully the community here can be of help.

The data is stored as a list of arrays. Each component in the list represent data grouped by a specific factor. The arrays have three dimensions. The first dimension represents time, the second dimension represents number of constituents, and the third dimension represents data points. So in the example data below each constituent (second dimension) has three data points (third dimension) per time unit (first dimension).

The first and third dimension have a fixed nrow (time) and ncol (data points), while the second dimension varies for each group (components in the list) which I why stored the arrays in a list.

So the data would be structured as below.

```
data.list <- vector("list", 3) 

numb <- c(2,3,4)

data.list[[1]] <- array(1:(numb[1] * 5 * 3), dim = c(5, numb[1], 3))
data.list[[2]] <- array(1:(numb[2] * 5 * 3), dim = c(5, numb[2], 3))
data.list[[3]] <- array(1:(numb[3] * 5 * 3), dim = c(5, numb[3], 3))
```

If I wanted to calculate the mean over time for the first data point across all constituents in group 1 (given it is not stored in a list) I would just do:

```
apply(array[,, "data.point.1"], 1, mean)
```

Now I want to apply mean over rows (time) across all groups (components in the list) and across constituents (second dimension in the arrays) - but I cannot find a solution.

I have tried to use sapply because essentially I would like to get a vector as the output with the length corresponding to nrow of the arrays (essentially the number of time periods in this problem). However, sapply would apply a function on each component and return a vector with the length of the list (at least that is what happened for me).

Can anybody see a good solution to this problem?

If not, is the fundamental problem then, that the data might be stored the wrong way for the type of computation I want to make?

Comment: Hm, yeah it is a bit confusing without a sample expected output. I think OP wants this: `lapply(data.list, function(x) apply(x,3,rowMeans))`.

Comment: nograpes your solution is almost right. However, you are right it is a bit confusing. I have edited the question to simplify the data structure and with "easier" numbers. With the new data the mean for the first data point (column in the third dimension) across the five components for all constituents (second dimension in the arrays) for the first time period should be 121. The function should essentially return a vector of length 100 corresponding to the time period.

Comment: working along nograpes' thoughts this:  sapply(data.list, function(x) apply(x[,,1],1, mean)) gives the mean per time unit for each component - essentially a 100 x 5 matrix. How to get this down to a 100 x 1 vector of the mean per row for the above matrix in one line of code - without storing the matrix and then use apply on the matrix creating multiple lines of code?

Comment: @P.Garnry I'd venture a guess that you're not getting many responses because your example data is way too large and given that the description isn't very good either no one is bothering to decipher what you wrote (certainly I'm not). I'd suggest coming up with a **much** smaller example (one that would fit on one page if printed) and an expected output for that example.

Comment: point taken @eddi I have simplified even more now. The mean for the first and second time period across the three components (in the list) across all constituents (the second dimension in the arrays) for the first data point (the first column in the third dimension) is > 

mean(c(1,6,1,6,11,1,6,11,16))
[1] 6.555556
> mean(c(2,7,2,7,12,2,7,12,17))
[1] 7.555556

Does it make sense now? So the function should return a vector with the length (nrow of the arrays in the list) - in this new simplified case the length should be five.

Comment: I experimented for a while and actually got a solution although I don't think it is pretty code wise.

apply(matrix(unlist(sapply(data.list, function(x) x[,,1])),5,9),1,mean)

[1]  6.555556  7.555556  8.555556  9.555556 10.555556

But it returns a vector with the length of five with the mean per time unit across all components for all constituents (second dimension in the array) for the first data point.

Is this really the best solution or can it be simplified even more...?

Answer (score 0):

I still don't understand OP, but this will generalize and slightly simplify the formula in the comments:

```
rowMeans(do.call(cbind, lapply(data.list, function(x) x[,,1])))
```